# Quarkus service endpoint always returns system info only

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus

I can confirm that the endpoints are working in the unittest through `io.restassured.RestAssured`. However, after I launched the service, every endpoint always returns a page of system info, e.g.

```
# HELP kafka_producer_node_request_total The total number of requests sent
# TYPE kafka_producer_node_request_total counter
kafka_producer_node_request_total{client_id="kafka-producer-metric-message-out",kafka_version="2.5.0",node_id="node--1",} 2.0
# HELP kafka_producer_connection_close_total The total number of connections closed
# TYPE kafka_producer_connection_close_total counter
kafka_producer_connection_close_total{client_id="kafka-producer-metric-message-out",kafka_version="2.5.0",} 0.0
# HELP kafka_producer_request_total The total number of requests sent
# TYPE kafka_producer_request_total counter
kafka_producer_request_total{client_id="kafka-producer-metric-message-out",kafka_version="2.5.0",} 2.0
# HELP kafka_producer_node_response_total The total number of responses received
# TYPE kafka_producer_node_response_total counter
kafka_producer_node_response_total{client_id="kafka-producer-metric-message-out",kafka_version="2.5.0",node_id="node--1",} 2.0
# HELP kafka_producer_node_response_rate The number of responses received per second
# TYPE kafka_producer_node_response_rate gauge
```

From the log I can see that the DBs are connected and schemas are evolved,
but where does such this info come from and why does it hijack my normal endpoints?

Comment: This is the metrics info, you should have include one of the smallrye-metrics or micrometer-metrics extension.
But this page should only be displayed on /q/metrics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a coincidence, it turned out that my application end point is also `/metrics`, and the `quarkus.http.non-application-root-path=/`, and therefore it keeps getting hijacked by quarkus metrics.
Thanks to @loicmathieu.

The solution is to configure the quarkus metrics endpoint:

```
quarkus.http.non-application-root-path=/
quarkus.smallrye-health.root-path=/quarkus-metrics/health
quarkus.smallrye-health.ui.root-path=/quarkus-metrics/health-ui
```